# Azure App Insights not showing all requests

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Since lately, App Insights for our App Service is not logging all requests and all failures. The actual number of requests is many times more than what App Insights is showing.
The strange thing is that there *are* some logged events in the App Insights, but the actual number is much higher. What could be the issue?

[image]

UPDATE: I checked data sampling setting, it has not changed recently and is set to 100% (All data) in `App Insights -> Usage and estimated cost`. From the chart on this page it can be seen that the number of events dropped significantly since May 11. I am not aware of any thing that would cause the drop in the number of events.

[image]

Comment: It's likely to be [sampling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43266877/314291).

Comment: I checked data sampling setting, and it is set to 100% (All data), we have not changed this  setting recently.

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same issue today and I believe the answer is indeed related with sampling, as suggested by others. The caveat is that the sampling you refer in Azure Portal (100%) is not being taken in consideration if you have other sampling settings in place (i.e. adaptive or fixed-rate sampling).

When you change the sampling in Azure Portal (also known as ingestion sampling), you see the following note:

> There may be additional sampling also happening by the SDK before data
> is sent to the Application Insights servers. If your SDK has adaptive
> sampling enabled or you have manually added code to enable sampling,
> no ingestion sampling will be applied regardless of the setting above.
> Learn more about Data Sampling

If you look at the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling), you'll also read the following about ingestion sampling:

> It only applies when no other sampling is in effect. If the SDK samples
> your telemetry, ingestion sampling is disabled.

Note also that if you have a ASP.NET / ASP.NET Core application deployed, you'll have adaptive sampling **enabled by default**, which might explain why your data is being sampled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Thanks to @StuartLC for pointing towards the right direction.*

There will be no problem with loading all of the data for small and medium loads of app services. However, few app services contain a large amount of data, it is impossible to retrieve all logs or requests and at times exceeds the quota. It also raises the cost expenditures. In this case, sampling is the most effective approach.

Refer MSDoc for [Sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling?tabs=net-core-new).

There can be multiple ways of enabling sampling & it is clearly detailed in the above doc.

*Check:*

> The sampling decision is based on the operation ID of the request, which means that all telemetry items belonging to a particular operation is either preserved or dropped.

*Or*

App Insights can be filtered out some requests and failures based on the configured filters using [Filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling) approach.

*You can check all these in configuration settings of application insights.*

Unlike sampling, you have complete control over what is sent or rejected in filtering, but it will have an impact on any metrics based on aggregated logs.

Goto `Application Insights -> Usage and estimated costs ->. Data sampling`. Choose the percentage of data to be sampled as shown:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the setting, and data sampling is set to 100% (All data). We have not changed this setting recently. The question is updated.